# TSC Printer Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined Error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, tsc

i have this error in Chrome "Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined "

My code is

```
        let TSCObj
        TSCObj = new ActiveXObject("TSCActiveX.TSCLIB")
        TSCObj.ActiveXopenport("TSC Alpha-2R")
        TSCObj.ActiveXsendcommand("SIZE 50 mm, 50 mm")
        TSCObj.ActiveXsendcommand("SPEED 4")
        TSCObj.ActiveXsendcommand("DENSITY 12")
        TSCObj.ActiveXsendcommand("DIRECTION 1")
        TSCObj.ActiveXsendcommand("SET TEAR ON")
        TSCObj.ActiveXclearbuffer()
        TSCObj.ActiveXbarcode("100", "40", "128", "50", "1", "0", "2", "2", "123456789")
        TSCObj.ActiveXprintlabel("1","1")
        TSCObj.ActiveXcloseport()
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't support ActiveX.
Only IE works with it.

Comment: Could you please add a source to support your affirmation?